# Select count and aggregate, but only unique

Tags: sql, unique, aggregate

I have a database (MSSQL) with a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ciphers](
    [Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [Hostname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ClientIP] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UserAgent] [varchar](550) NULL,
    [CipherName] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [CipherVersion] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CipherBits] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

A couple of rows can look like this:

[image]

Now I want to count the number of occurrences of the combination of CipherName, CipherVersion and CipherBits for each top level domain.

Almost like this:

```
SELECT CipherName, CipherVersion, CipherBits, COUNT(ClientIP) As "Hits" 
from Ciphers
WHERE Hostname like '%domain.com' 
Group by CipherName, CipherVersion, CipherBits
```

The crux is that I only want to count unique instances of each client IP. That is, if a customer has browsed to sub.domain.com and test.domain.com I don't want to count this as two, just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you aren't grouping by `HostName`, it looks like all you need is [`COUNT(DISTINCT x)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx):

```
SELECT CipherName, CipherVersion, CipherBits, COUNT(DISTINCT ClientIP) As "Hits" 
from Ciphers
WHERE Hostname like '%domain.com' 
Group by CipherName, CipherVersion, CipherBits;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb3f3/1)

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try this -

```
SELECT CipherName, CipherVersion, CipherBits, COUNT(DISTINCT ClientIP) OVER (PARTITION BY CipherName, CipherVersion, CipherBits) As "Hits" 
from Ciphers
WHERE Hostname like '%domain.com';
```

Comment: Nice query my friend but `Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause`.

Comment: It works -- 
SELECT CipherName, CipherVersion, CipherBits, COUNT(DISTINCT ClientIP) OVER (PARTITION BY CipherName, CipherVersion, CipherBits) As "Hits" 
from 
(
select '10.105.69.92' ClientIP, 'a.domain.com' Hostname, 'a' CipherName, 1  CipherVersion,  10 CipherBits from dual
union all
select '10.105.69.92' ClientIP, 'c.domain.com' Hostname, 'a'  CipherName, 1  CipherVersion,  10 CipherBits from dual
)
Ciphers
WHERE Hostname like '%domain.com';

Comment: My bad. I ran the query in Oracle and it actually allows my query to run. I did not realize that SQL SERVER does not allow that.